Create a Reels-like swipable video feed in Flutter
Given an array of 20 videos. need to preload the next Videos for the first 10 seconds of every video and present them in reels format flutter. Please advise how to do it with example way.. seamless video without loading....
Tried using whitecodel_reels but get stuck in various parts list video.
Some personal way of cache and loading controller no luck

Combination of

Preload page view
Cache video

These can slightly enhance performance.
Make sure to dispose the video controller timely and play around with the cache extent.
